# Java: Check equality of two arrays based on user input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, equality

I want to see if the following boolean value returns true if the first n elements of two arrays are equal. In other words if n is 5 then the first 5 elements of the two arrays are equal and the method should return true.

```
@Override

public boolean equal(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {       
    //goes through each value in the s array
    for (int i =0; i < s[n]; i++){                    
        //goes through each value in the t array
        for (int j = 0 ; i < t[n]; j++){                           
            if (s[n] == t[n]){                    
                return true;                    
            }                
        }
    }                
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to read more on the Java programming language. Seems like you deeply misunderstand certain basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the nested for loop. Here is a more concise algorithm.

```
public boolean equal(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {

    //TODO: you can add checks to make sure n is less than the length of both of the arrays

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        //For the first n elements, if they aren't equal just return false;
        if(s[i] != t[i]){

            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in the code. Below is one way of checking whether the first `n` entries of the arrays equal.

```
boolean equal(char[] t, char[] s, int n) {
    if (s.length <= n || t.length <= n) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != t[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```